# Netty 4: deferred ctx.write

Tags: scala, netty, future

Based on the 'helloworld' HTTP example (Netty 4.0.12.Final), I'd like to somehow defer writing of a HTTP response, i.e. the request handling and response creation should be executed outside Netty's workers. After the response is available, Netty should pick up where it left and write the response to the channel.

The following code should demonstrate what I want to achieve. Problem is, that in case of handleDeferred() Netty blocks somewhere down the road and the response never hits the client. I'm not sure whether I'm completely off-track here. So any suggestions are appreciated.

```
import io.netty.channel.{ChannelFutureListener, ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter}
import io.netty.handler.codec.http._
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaders.Values
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled
import scala.concurrent._

class DispatchingHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

  class StaticResponseFactory {
    def response = {
      val content = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("Hey there!".getBytes)
      val response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK, content)
      response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain")
      response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes())
      response
    }
  }

  override def channelRead(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: Any) {
    val deferred = true // <= select how to respond.
    msg match {
      case request: HttpRequest if deferred => handleDeferred(ctx, request)
      case request: HttpRequest => handleImmediately(ctx, request)
      case lastHttpContent: LastHttpContent => /* ignore trailing headers */
      case other => println("unexpected message: " + other)
    }
  }

  override def channelReadComplete(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext) {
    println("[" + Thread.currentThread() + "] flushing...")
    ctx.flush()
  }

  override def exceptionCaught(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, cause: Throwable) {
    cause.printStackTrace()
  }

  def handleImmediately(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, request: HttpRequest) {
    val response = new StaticResponseFactory().response
    writeResponse(ctx, request, response)
  }

  def handleDeferred(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, request: HttpRequest) {
    // execute dispatch and request handling on Scala-managed thread pool (global).
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    future(dispatchRequestAndCollectResponse(request)).onSuccess { case factory =>
      writeResponse(ctx, request, factory.response)
    }
  }

  def writeResponse(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, request: HttpRequest, response: FullHttpResponse) {
    if (!HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(request)) {
      val channelFuture = ctx.write (response)
      channelFuture.addListener (ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)
    } else {
      response.headers ().set (HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, Values.KEEP_ALIVE)
      ctx.write (response)
    }
  }

  def dispatchRequestAndCollectResponse(request: HttpRequest): StaticResponseFactory = {
    // do some heavy lifting...
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    new StaticResponseFactory
  }
}
```

Comment: Flushing buffers (ctx.flush() in writeResponse(...)) did the trick.

Comment: That's right. Since 4.0, `write()` does not flush automatically. You have to flush manually or use `writeAndFlush()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Trustin for the confirmation.